# Neo4j JDBC setting ResultSet type to something other than default

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j

I am running a Neo4j server (2.0.3) and am accessing it via Cypher queries through the Neo4j JDBC. It works well for most of the uses I have had so far.

I currently want to run a query that will return a result set that is of the type - `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` and not the default `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

Here is the code I use to create my Statement and return the ResultSet:

```
Statement all = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
results = all.executeQuery(query);
```

However when I try and use the method `beforeFirst()` on the ResultSet I get an SQLException. Which is a result of either a closed ResultSet or one that is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`. I have used the `isClosed()` method to ensure it is not closed.

Within the [Neo4j JDBC Driver](https://github.com/rickardoberg/neo4j-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/jdbc/Neo4jConnection.java) there is the following createStatement method:

```
    @Override
public Statement createStatement(int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency) throws SQLException
{
    return debug(new Neo4jStatement(this));
}
```

So from what I can see, it is simply ignoring the type and concurrency constants that are passed to it. I realize not all JDBC drivers allow for different type result sets. I guess I am asking why the Neo4j one does not? And if not, are there any plans to implement support for this? I would find it useful, and thought others might as well?

Comment: Both are questions that you should direct to Neo4j. Note that the JDBC specification allows a driver to ignore your request: _"If the driver does not support the type supplied to the methods `createStatement`, `prepareStatement`, or `prepareCall`, it generates an `SQLWarning` on the `Connection` object that is creating the statement. When the statement is executed, the driver returns a ResultSet object of a type that most closely matches the requested type."_ (JDBC 4.2, section 15.1.1)

Comment: Currently the underlying APIs and query results only allow a single forward iteration. So there is not much the JDBC driver can do. What is your actual use-case?

Comment: Thanks Michael, this answer makes sense. I am extracting a set of data from my database and then using the result set to compare to another dataset, repeatedly. I did realize though that I am not ever going to be modifying the data from the result set so I don't need it in this object. I just took the data from the result set into my own objects and use those for my algorithm. I think this is a better solution anyways. Thanks for your response though, good to know for future use.